# Select value and count from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one stores the user's information with a referral ID.
The other table collects records and applies the referral ID from which I arrived at that form.

I have made 2 queries that I want to join in a single query.

**Example query for ID = 205391**

```
---- Select email from refer 205391
SELECT email FROM mautic_leads WHERE refer_id IN 
(SELECT refer_id FROM mautic_form_results_64_form_db_te WHERE refer_id = "205391")
```

```
---- Count results of refer 205391
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `mautic_form_results_64_form_db_te` where ref = 205391)
```

I'm looking for the result to be:

```
Email |  Count Ref
---------------
test@test.com     5
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `mautic_form_results_64_form_db_te` (
  `submission_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `form_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `apellido` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `correo_electronico` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `ref` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `mautic_form_results_64_form_db_te` (`submission_id`, `form_id`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `correo_electronico`, `ref`) VALUES
(7699, 64, 'test', 'test', 'test@test.net', '201374'),
(7700, 64, 'test2', 'test2', 'test@test.net', '205391'),
(7701, 64, 'test3', 'test3', 'test@test.net', '205391'),
(7704, 64, 'test4', 'test4', 'test@test.net', '205391'),
(7705, 64, 'test5', 'test5', 'test@test.net', '205391'),
(7706, 64, 'test6', 'test6', 'test@test.net', '201374'),
(7707, 64, 'test7', 'test7', 'test@test.net', '201374'),
(7708, 64, 'test8', ' test8 ', 'test@test.net', '205391');

CREATE TABLE `mautic_leads` (
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `refer_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `referido_por_usuario` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `mautic_leads` (`email`, `refer_id`, `referido_por_usuario`) VALUES
('test1@test.com', '201374', NULL),
('test2@test.com', '205388', NULL),
('test3@test.com', '205389', NULL),
('test3@test.com', '205390', NULL),
('test2@test.com', '205391', NULL);
```

Some help?
Thanks

Comment: *"Some help? Thanks"* Adding table structures, example data would also help here, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data. We can't answer with this limited information

Comment: Thanks, I added the structure of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query:

```
SELECT mautic_leads.email as email, (SELECT count(*) as count from \
mautic_form_results_64_form_db_te where ref = "205391") as count \
from mautic_leads where refer_id = "205391";
```

You will get the result like:

```
+----------------+-------+
| email          | count |
+----------------+-------+
| test2@test.com |     5 |
+----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT (SELECT email 
    FROM   mautic_leads 
    WHERE  refer_id IN (SELECT refer_id 
                        FROM   mautic_form_results_64_form_db_te 
                        WHERE  refer_id = "205391")) as email, 
   Count(*) AS `count` 
FROM   `mautic_form_results_64_form_db_te` 
WHERE  ref = 205391
```

Comment: I think it's on the right track since it throws me the information, as it could be without the ref = 205391 ?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see your table structure, use this:

```
SELECT b.email,COUNT(a.submission_id) as `count`
FROM mautic_form_results_64_form_db_te a
JOIN mautic_leads b on  b.refer_id = a.ref
WHERE ref = 205391
```

Comment: I tried but I got an error, I added the structure of the database. Thank you!